# Show UIWebView inside Cocoa Touch Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, oauth, uiwebview

I am working in a new Cocoa Touch Library and I need to show a UIWebView programatically because I'm going to request user and password (like oAuth) in a external web but I don't know how can I do this inside a Cocoa Touch Library.

Example code:

**Client.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Client : NSObject

@property NSString *_aProperty;

- (void)showUIWebView:(NSURL*)urlToOpen;

@end
```

**Client.m**

```
#import "Client.h"

@implementation Client

@synthesize _identity;

- (void)showUIWebView:(NSURL*)urlToOpen
{        
   // I need to write code here to show the UIWebView :) 
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to do this using such code:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIWebView *web = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 40, 300, 300)];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://yahoo.com"]];
[web loadRequest: req];
[app.keyWindow addSubview: web];
```

So the main idea is to add your view as subview to keyWindow of the application.

Comment: One question, where are going to execute the delegate methods of UIWebView?

Comment: `UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];` is this the root of the App?

Comment: You didn't asked about delegates :) Let me think

Comment: UIApplication is a main singleton, so you can access to it from any part of your application.

Comment: About delegate: your client has to be delegate of UIWebView, because users of your library don't know details about UIWebView you're going to show. If you need to notify users you can create own protocol and provide delegate for your client

Comment: It should work, we use the keyWindow in one of our apps to show custom alerts (instead of UIAlertView).

Comment: The object that creates the webview can handle the delegate methods.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned you can show UI elements in Cocoa-Touch only inside `UIViewControllers` - which seems pretty logical.

Inside your method in your `NSObject` you can trigger a method in another `UIViewController` by creating a reference to it and then add it to your `UIView` at this time:

```
- (void)showUIWebView:(NSURL*)urlToOpen {        
UIViewController *myVC = [self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject];
//This is your last view in the navigationController hierarchy.
UIWebView *newWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:myVC.view.frame];
[myVC.view addSubview:newWebView];
}
```

Or you can trigger it from another `ViewController` you are referencing this library from.

Comment: I like this part: `UIViewController *myVC = [self.navigationController.viewControllers lastObject];`

I'll try tomorrow :)

Comment: It will work if you have a `UINavigationController` and the view you want to access is the last one in view hierarchy (which is basically 99% of times).

Answer (score 0):

i would think that the simplest way to do this would be to have the call from the app into your library provide a superview into which you can then add your subview:

```
@interface ChemitaxisLibrary
typedef void (^ChemitaxisLibraryLoginCompletionBlock)(BOOL loggedIn);
- (void)loginWithinSuperview:(UIView*)superView completion:(ChemitaxisLibraryLoginCompletionBlock)completion;

@end
```

this will require the user of your code to provide the location within their app where they are willing to allow you to place your UIWebView* instance.

(the completion block with the BOOL indicating success or failure allows your library to manipulate the webview as you need, and when you get to the place where you can report back success or failure, the completion handle will give you a way to do this.)

once you have this, adding your UIWebView within their passed superview can be as simple or complex as you want to make it.  you can take over the entire frame, or you can take a corner, or you can be dynamic and decide what to do based on the size of the superView they give you to work with.

Answer (score 0):

This should do you.

You'll have to replace the Frame with the x,y,width,height of the web view respective to the view you add it to, and self.view with the variable where the parent view is stored.

For example if you wanted to add it to the root view (window) you could replace self.view with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].

```
- (void)showUIWebView:(NSURL*)urlToOpen {
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 460.0f)]; // WebView Location & Dimensions
    [webView loadRequest:[NSUrlRequest requestWithURL:urlToOpen]];

    [self.view addSubView:webView]; // Where self.view is the view you wish to add the Web View to.
}
```